# How to use opencv feature matching for detecting copy-move forgery

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, flann

In my opencv project, I want to detect copy-move forgery in an image. I know how to use the opencv FLANN for feature matching in 2 different image, but I am become so confused on how to use FLANN for detection copy-move forgery in an image.

P.S1: I get the sift keypoints and descriptors of image and stuck in using the feature matching class.

P.S2: the type of feature matching is not important for me.

Thanks in advance.

Update :

These pictures is an example of what I need

[image: Input Image]

[image: Result]

And There is a code which matches features of two images and do something like it on two images (not a single one), the code in android native opencv format is like below:

```
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
        Mat descriptors;

        // Create a SIFT keypoint detector.
        SiftFeatureDetector detector;
        detector.detect(image_gray, keypoints);
        LOGI("Detected %d Keypoints ...", (int) keypoints.size());

        // Compute feature description.
        detector.compute(image, keypoints, descriptors);
        LOGI("Compute Feature ...");


        FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
        std::vector< DMatch > matches;
        matcher.match( descriptors, descriptors, matches );

        double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

        //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
          for( int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows; i++ )
          { double dist = matches[i].distance;
            if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
            if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
          }

          printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
          printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

          //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist,
          //-- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is very
          //-- small)
          //-- PS.- radiusMatch can also be used here.
          std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

          for( int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows; i++ )
          { if( matches[i].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 0.02) )
            { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
          }

          //-- Draw only "good" matches
          Mat img_matches;
          drawMatches( image, keypoints, image, keypoints,
                       good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
                       vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

          //-- Show detected matches
//          imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );
          imwrite(imgOutFile, img_matches);
```

Comment: Showing your current code and samples of images you are working with would definitely be helpful.

Comment: @user3896254 thanks for your advice, I edit my post and add example and code

Comment: @all do you know how to achieve copy move forgery for fonts(character/digit) in images using python ?

Comment: @MohamadMohamadPoor Did you ever find a satisfactory answer to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's a good idea to use keypoints for this problem. I'd rather test [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) (using a sliding window on your image as patch). Compared to keypoints, this method has the disadvantage of being sensible to rotation and scale.

If you want to use keypoints, you can :

- find a set of keypoints (SURF, SIFT, or whatever you want),
- compute the matching score with every other keypoints, with the `knnMatch` function of the Brute Force Matcher (`cv::BFMatcher`),
- keep matches between distincts points, i.e. points whose distance is greater than zero (or a threshold).

  ```
  int nknn = 10; // max number of matches for each keypoint
  double minDist = 0.5; // distance threshold

  // Match each keypoint with every other keypoints
  cv::BFMatcher matcher(cv::NORM_L2, false);
  std::vector< std::vector< cv::DMatch > > matches;
  matcher.knnMatch(descriptors, descriptors, matches, nknn);

  double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
  for( int i = 0; i < descriptors.rows; i++ )
  { 
      double dist = matches[i].distance;
      if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
      if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
  }

  // Compute distance and store distant matches
  std::vector< cv::DMatch > good_matches;
  for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < matches[i].size(); j++)
      {
          // The METRIC distance
          if( matches[i][j].distance> max(2*min_dist, 0.02) )
              continue;

          // The PIXELIC distance
          Point2f pt1 = keypoints[queryIdx].pt;
          Point2f pt2 = keypoints[trainIdx].pt;

          double dist = cv::norm(pt1 - pt2);
          if (dist > minDist)
              good_matches.push_back(matches[i][j]);
      }
  }

  Mat img_matches;
  drawMatches(image_gray, keypoints, image_gray, keypoints, good_matches, img_matches);
  ```

Comment: @Evil this is the advice I would follow. If you have an image of what needs to be detected then use template matching. Otherwise, go with the example shown by Gwen.

Comment: @Gwen I was so busy this week, I will try your solution and let your know what happened, BTW thanks for your answer and thanks for alternative solution but I need to use keypoints.

Comment: @Gwen I've tried your sample code, but at the end it doesn't get me the result I need, it give me the lots of matching and doesn't show in a single image !!! (showed on two same image beside each other ...), Is there any further help? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Evil I corrected the distance computation (I used the metric distance instead of the pixellic distance...). Code not tested, but the idea is here. But, as I said, I cannot guarantee that this approach will work.

Comment: @Gwen thanks for your reply, it doesn't meet what I need, but thanks for your idea.